# Ubuntu Network Permissions

Tags: networking, permissions

I am too lazy to get up off the couch to walk over to my Ubuntu 11.04 box to change some file permissions.  I realize asking this question takes more effort than getting up, but curiosity got the better of me.

I am able to do anything to this Windows laptop from my Ubuntu machine via the network, by simply logging in as the administrator of the machine.

Is there a way to gain root access to my Ubuntu public folder from the network via this Windows laptop?  I have Samba server setup on the Ubuntu box, but no remote desktop of any kind.

Please help me, because I want to watch Apocolypse Now, but I am far too lazy to get up.

Thanks in advance,

Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the reasons why geeks love GNU with Linux. It's seriously awesome when it comes to network access. Anything Windows can do, is just a pale shadow in comparison. The master tool is SSH. Using it, you can accomplish anything that you can do on the console from any computer client, be it a mobile phone or a smart tv. If you want a remote desktop solution, then I would recommend using X2go from http://x2go.org. It's free software, easily installed and quite user friendly.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying that I could install SSH on the windows machine, and as long as I know the Linux box's root password, I could change folder permissions on a folder I only have read access to from the Windows box?

Comment: Yes. Actually, you don't need, and shouldn't use, a root password. Log in as your primary user, or another user in the admin group and use sudo. Putty is a good ssh client for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take a look at the Ubuntu official guide on Samba and specifically on Samba clients:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba